# Embed .exe in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am looking for a way to embed an .exe into a frame.  (MDI)

I am not sure how this can be done.

I am using wxpython 2.9 and there is nothing online about this (until now).

Comment: What sort of .exe are you talking about?  Console programs don't draw in GUI's at all, and GUI programs already have their own UI.

Comment: Like notepad.exe on Windows, I would embed that into the frame. It would not open a new window but it would be inside my wxpython app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ned has pointed out, embedding other GUI applications into wxPython is non-trivial. There are several Notepad-like programs written in wxPython that you could use, including Editra and Ulipad. You would need access to OLE or ActiveX: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/473601-embed-notepad-into-frame-widget

Comment: I am not actually using Notepad of course, I am just using it as an example. How can I do this with OLE?

Comment: You'd probably have to look at PyWin32 or ctypes

Answer (score 0):

Embedding one GUI application inside another is not a simple thing.  Applications are written to provide their own main frame, for example.  You could try to position Notepad to a particular place on the screen instead.

If you're really talking about Notepad, then you have a different course of action.  Notepad is nothing more than a text control with some code to save and load the contents to a file.

Comment: I used to use a program called 'Game Maker', This program is designed for people 12+ and it has this feature. I thought that it couldn't be that difficult.